# Handbrake 1.1 cannot load preset

Tags: linux-mint, handbrake

Trying to load the preset offered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1609653/1039759), after saving as `json` and importing the preset, I cannot enable it.

It is absent in the list of presets under any category. And I don't see a separate custom category.

What am I missing?

This is on Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, Handbrake 1.1.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up [the official website](https://handbrake.fr/), I see a more recent version there (1.3). [Adding the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Estebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases) and installing `handbrake-gtk` I get 1.2.1 version (because my system in ubuntu-18.04-based, newer versions of Ubuntu should get even newer versions): this has a different interface, one with a button that was absent in the other version.

[image]

[image]

Also, the preset is automatically loaded after bring imported.

Testing again with `handbrake` old 1.1 (which removes the newer version) it gives upon startup a warning that **presets newer than the present version of Handbrake are present**.